How to setup RabbitMQ consumer worker in python flask app
I'm trying to build a microservice in flask where I would have only a worker that will consume messages from a rabbitmq Queue1,and send some payload back to another queue.
So, after the consuming from Queue1, I have a method preProcessData() which needs to be called, and after that send a response to Queue2.
On my RabbitMQ server, I have defined Queue1, Queue2, Direct-Exchange-1 and Direct-Exchange-2.
Can someone provide a simple implementation of this?
I have very little experience in flask, overall.
Any help is appreciated, thanks
